# Common Htaccess file - Adding Redirect in Condition

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to know what redirection rule should be in my .htacess file, which is common for multiple websites

What I want is something like :

```
http://example.com/asq_question.php
```

to be redirected to

```
http://example.com/faq
```

I've tried many examples but they won't work.
My last failed Rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^faq/$  http://www.example.com/asq_question.php [P]
```

Comment: I just applied some examples found in the Internet, i'm new to this field. can you help out there ?

Comment: Try this rule: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/asq_question\.php$ /faq`

Comment: My Issue, is that i have multiple websites that use the same .htaccess file, which mean i have to specify which domaine name (website) or else this will be applied to all websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer since I cannot post multiline code in comments;

Try this rule in site root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^asq_question\.php$ /faq? [L,NC,R=301]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Hi
that works fine, since i've sub domaine, i just changed
^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
to 
^sub.domain.com